# Podcasts, and where the audio file is

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm writing a podcast aggregator in Python. I've found that most podcasts have the audio file linked under a `link` tag. But some don't: for example [the Nature podcast](http://feeds.nature.com/nature/podcast/current) has it under `origEnclosureLink` tags.

Many podcast aggregators have no problem downloading the Nature podcast, so I assume that people know something that I don't about which tags (tend to) carry the meat in a podcast feed. Could someone enlighten me about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..which tags (tend to) carry the meat in a podcast feed

- [RSS 2.0](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html): `<enclosure`
- [Atom](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287.txt): `<link rel="enclosure"`
- [`<media:content xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"`](http://video.search.yahoo.com/mrss)
- `<feedburner:origEnclosureLink xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0"`

The Nature podcast feed is RSS 2.0.